# Insert at a specific position List<List<Map<Integer,Integer>>>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, insert, iterator

I'm new to Java. I need a way to insert value to Map in `List<List<Map<Integer,Integer>>>` at a specyfic position. Any ideas how to do it?

E.g. i need to work on my list like on 2d array, so for instance I need to insert value at `tab[0][0] = value`. I need similar operation on `List<List<Map<Integer,Integer>>>`

Comment: Check this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)

Comment: How do you mean "insert"? Do you want to replace an existing value, or should all existing values move along one place?

Comment: E.g. i need to work on my list like on 2d array, so for instance I need to insert value at 
<code>
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
   tab[0][i] = value;
   tab[i][0] = value;
}
</code>

Comment: My main issue is how to get to position equal to tab[i][0] in my List<List<Map<Integer,Integer>>>. I've never worked with Iterators before.

Comment: @ninigi You need to show us some code. I can do this, but it is not clear what you already have. Is the list already full of values?

Comment: here goes the code: http://wklej.org/id/2168633/    I need to put things to matrix

Comment: Must you use a List<List<Map<>>>? Can you instead use a Map<Map<Map<>>>? :O

Comment: Due to actions which follow I must use List<List<Map<>>>

Answer (score 1):

Access by index on lists is done via [`List.get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-). So, write:

```
tab.get(0).set(0, newMap);
```

Of course, your lists must be correctly initialised to the appropriate sizes for [`get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) and [`set(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) to work

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert nested list into array or you want to map values to array. Here is a small snippet how to achieve it.

```
List<List<Map<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Map<Integer, Integer>>();

for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
      for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
           array[i][j] = list.get(i).get(j);
           /*
           list.get(i) retrieves the i row
           .get(j) retrieves the column 
           */
      }
}
```

Comment: What is array in here?

Comment: You want to map values from list to array?? or array to list??